# How to do a $C-PH$ gate in google cirq

Tags: quantum-gate, cirq

I know that I can just use the $RZ$ gate to replace the $PH$ phase gate. But I need a way to implement the controlled phase gate $C-PH$ this cannot just be replaced with a $CRZ$ gate.

Comment: Could you expand your question? Not sure what you are confused by.

Comment: to do an $RZ$ on google cirq I can use `cirq.ops.common_gates.Rz`. I didn't find any way to do a phase gate on google cirq, so I just replaced all of my phase gates into $RZ$ gates. Now that I have controlled phase gates, I don't know how to implement that on google cirq because even though an RZ does the same as a Phase gate, the controlled version don't, because the controlled version of a gate does change with global phase shifts.

Comment: Can you not compensate with RZ on each of the two qubits?

Comment: I could, but I came here to find the minimal amount of gate, or some kind of workaround like if it was possible to define my own abstract gate in google cirq.

Comment: the documentation mentions circ.CZ, and the possibility to use it to do things like cirq.CZ**t

Comment: according to the documentation cirq.ZPowGate(exponent=t) is defined as [[1, 0],[0, e^(i*pi*t)]] so if I use cirq.ZPowGate(exponent=t/pi) I can actually get a phase gate.

Answer (score 1):

`cirq.ZPowGate(exponent=t/pi).controlled_by(control_qubit).on(target_qubit)`

or equivalently

`cirq.CZ(control_qubit, target_qubit)**(t / pi)`